# Multilayered find and update mongodb and nodejs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

Learning MongoDB so I hope that this is not a duplicate question.

So big picture. Users can add/remove items from their cart (which is an array).

The cart array holds objects who are structured as follows: {_id: 123r32, qty: 2}

The user document is structured as follows:

```
_id: 123432423,
username: johndoe,
email: johndoe@mail.com,
cart: [
  {
    _id: wefw3423,
    qty: 100
  }
]
```

So adding to the array is fine:

```
db.users.updateOne({_id: req.user.id}, {$push: {cart: {_id: req.body.id, qty: req.body.qty}}})
```

But when I push, I don't want to add a duplicate. I want to just adjust the qty (add/subtract) accordingly. If no instance of that _id exists, push.

Thank you for reading and your help! Should you need additional information, please ask I shall provide!.

EDIT:

Additional information. The request body (req.body) will contain only ONE item. So updateMany will not be required here.

Comment: Please tell you want to one query for resolve this problem ???

Comment: Since my experience with mongo is almost nil, please provide your best solution. 

Thank you,

Comment: firstly we check that cart id and  pull and after push cart data in document

Answer (score 0):

```
db.users.updateOne({_id: req.user.id}, {$set: { "cart.$[element]": {_id:"wefw3423",qty:50}}, { arrayFilters: [ { element: _id:"wefw3423" } ]},{ upsert:true})
```

MongoDB reference :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#mongodb-update-up.---identifier--